# Unable to break at DriverEntry of malicious Driver

Tags: windbg, kernel-mode

I got a malicious kernel mode driver from VirusTotal. Now, I am trying to debug it using Windbg.

Below are the details of the setup:

Host OS: Win 7 Ultimate 64-bit, Windbg version 6.11.x, VMWare Workstation and Guest OS: Win XP SP3

I placed the kernel mode driver in Guest OS in the path: C:\drivers\test

Added .sys extension to the kernel mode driver.

In Windbg on Host OS, I attached to the guest OS through Named Pipe. Set the breakpoint to break at DriverEntry of the driver as shown below:

```
bu malicious_driver!DriverEntry
```

Then press g.

In Guest OS, used OSR Driver Loader from osronline.com to load the driver.

Browsed for the Driver, Registered the Service and started the Service.

I break in Windbg however I receive the following error message:

```
kd> bu malicious_driver!DriverEntry
kd> g
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for malicious_driver.sys
Breakpoint 0's offset expression evaluation failed.
Check for invalid symbols or bad syntax.
WaitForEvent failed
nt!DebugService2+0x11:
8052e4c5 5d              pop     ebp
kd> !drvobj malicious_driver
Driver object (b25eb000) is for:
b25eb000: is not a driver object
```

Please note that I am able to successfully break at the DriverEntry of known legitimate Microsoft Windows OS drivers like ndis.sys, http.sys

However, how do I break at the entry point of malicious drivers as in this case? I don't have the symbols for them either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try "break on module load" (e.g. `sxe ld malicious_driver.sys`). When it's hit, you can check the driver's load address and set  breakpoint by address.